# Open WebView in Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, ibaction

Can someone tell me how I can make an IBAction that opens the current link in the WebView in Safari.
So ​​that all pages I open that WebView can be opened with that one button in Safari.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)openLink {
    NSURL * currentURL = [myWebView.request URL];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:currentURL];
}
```

This should mostly work for URLs loaded via `loadRequest:` or traversed from there but won't work for other local load methods like `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`

Comment: How can i put this in a UIActionSheet?Thanks:)